# NetBeans generates JpaController with errors

Tags: java, hibernate, netbeans, jpa, spring-mvc

I am using NetBeans 6.8 for building Spring MVC application.

Technologies :

- Spring MVC 2.5
- Derby DB
- Hibernate for ORM
- GlassFish v3 server

I use **New JPA Controller Classes from Entity Classes** for adding ORM file. It is supposed to generate class for managing queries with my POJO files.

Problem is, that NetBeans generates following code, and won't compile :

```
public int getBrandCount() {
        EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
        try {
            CriteriaQuery cq = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
            Root<Brand> rt = cq.from(Brand.class);
            cq.select(em.getCriteriaBuilder().count(rt));
            Query q = em.createQuery(cq);
            return ((Long) q.getSingleResult()).intValue();
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }
```

At the picture, there is NetBeans error :
[image]

It looks like method `getCriteriaBuilder` of [Entity Manager Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html) is unimplemented. Or some other reason why I can't use it in code.

I don't know what other info should I provide, so please ask if anything comes to your mind.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NetBeans is generating JPA 2.0 code so you need the JPA 2.0 API on your class path to compile your code (and a JPA 2.0 provider to run it). Since you're using Hibernate, here are  the required libraries to use Hibernate Entity Manager 3.5.1-Final:

```
org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:3.5.1-Final:compile
+- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.5.1-Final:compile
|  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.6:compile
|  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2:compile
|  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
|  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
|  \- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile
+- org.hibernate:hibernate-annotations:jar:3.5.1-Final:compile
|  \- org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:3.2.0.Final:compile
+- cglib:cglib:jar:2.2:compile
|  \- asm:asm:jar:3.1:compile
+- javassist:javassist:jar:3.9.0.GA:compile
\- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
```

Comment: It seems that JPA 2.0 + Derby DB aren't great friends. It actually works better with MySQL :-|

Comment: This has IMO nothing to do with MySQL or Derby (which works fine with JPA 2.0).

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem and found that I had the Hibernate JPA library (included with Netbeans) above Persistence (JPA 2.0) library in the project library manager list.  I moved Persistence above Hibernate and it cleared up the compile issues.

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar problem when deploying project with

- Netbeans 7.0.1
- Apache Tomcat 7
- Hibernate 3

When mapping the class entity from database, i mixed it with annotation so the controller can be easily generated by Java Persistence Controller. The problem is same. The getCriteriaBuilder is the problem since it isn't supported by JPA 1.0. I have checked it in the project classpath and i found that Persistence Library is miss used since the project import two persistence library which is persistence library from ejb3 and EclipseLink(JPA2.0).

When i remove the ejb persistence library, the getCriteriaBuilder works fine for me.